# Serving up WCF Services in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, model-view-controller, servicehost

I'm wondering if it's possible to service up WCF services via MVC.  I've seen a few posts about this as it relates to RESTful services, but I'm not looking to create a RESTful service.

I've also seen this topic covered as far as serving up .svc files from MVC, but I'm not looking for that either.

Basically, I'm just looking to expose my WCF services via MVC, instead of a typical Wep App type structure with svc files.

so instead of having ttp://localhost/MyService.svc, I would just have ttp://localhost/MyService and that would go to a controller that would return the data.

Is it possible to have a "servicehost" controller?  I would assume that the biggest obstacle to this would be that IIS handles the service a certain way based on the .svc extension - would some kind of custom handler have to be set up for something like this?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without MVC (or, it seems, with it too)

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/09/22/wcf-rest-services-inside-mvc-projects.aspx

Comment: Although I'm specifically not looking to use the RESTful architecture, the first link you posted may help get me in the right direction.  I'll have to do some testing with it.  Thanks.